# Problem with getting file URLs of folders inside multiple directories

Tags: php

Here is my code to get a list of the file URLs inside a specific directory:

**PHP**

```
<?php
function getDirContents($directories, &$results = array()){

    $files = array_diff(scandir($directories), array('..', '.'));;
    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = $directories.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
        if(is_dir($path)) {
          getDirContents($path, $results);
        } else {
          $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
          $results[] =  'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

$directories = "directory_A";
echo json_encode(getDirContents($directories));
```

The result for directory_A:

```
https://example.com/directory_A/voice1.mp3
https://example.com/directory_A/Media/inside_media_1/voice2.mp3
https://example.com/directory_A/Media/inside_media_1/voice3.mp3
```

What if we want to get URLs from multiple directories?

I tried to loop through those directories using a for loop like this:

```
<?php
function getDirContents($directories, &$results = array()){

    $length = count($directories);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

    $files = array_diff(scandir($directories[$i]), array('..', '.'));;
    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = $directories[$i].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
        if(is_dir($path)) {
          getDirContents($path, $results);
        } else {
          $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
          $results[] =  'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
        }
    }

    }

    return $results;
}


$directories = array("directory_A", "directory_B");

echo json_encode(getDirContents($directories));
```

But I only get the files inside those directories and code dosn't go to the folders inside each directory so I only get this for directory_A:

```
https://example.com/directory_A/voice1.mp3
```

What I'm missing and how to fix this?

Comment: In the second version, the call to getDirContents has to be an array. Change `getDirContents($path, $results);` to `getDirContents([$path], $results);`

Comment: I'll try that...

Comment: That worked ...if you prepare an answer it would be accepted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array and a string to the function. You have two options. You can always send in an array, or you can look for a string and convert it to an array.

```
class GoDir
{
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $directories = array("storage", "config");
        echo json_encode($this->getDirContents($directories));
    }

    public function getDirContents($directories, &$results = array())
    {
        // See if we got a string and convert to array
        if ( is_string($directories) ) {
            $directories = [$directories];
        }
        $length = count($directories);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $files = array_diff(scandir($directories[$i]), array('..', '.'));;
            foreach($files as $key => $value){
                $path = $directories[$i].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
                if(is_dir($path)) {
                    $this->getDirContents($path, $results);
                } else {
                    $directory_path = '/';
                    $results[] =  $directory_path . $path;
                }
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }

    // Here is an alternative solution:

    public function getDirContents($directories, &$results = array())
    {
        $length = count($directories);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $files = array_diff(scandir($directories[$i]), array('..', '.'));;
            foreach($files as $key => $value){
                $path = $directories[$i].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
                if(is_dir($path)) {
                    // Turn the param into an array
                    $this->getDirContents([$path], $results);
                } else {
                    $directory_path = '/';
                    $results[] =  $directory_path . $path;
                }
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```